# ejabberd having issue about undefined function

Tags: gentoo, ejabberd

I am getting errors with XMPP on my Gentoo Hardened server. It runs and says it is running but when trying log many of these errors appear about a crash.

```
2019-11-01 10:56:54.748 [error] <0.563.0>@xmpp_idna:domain_utf8_to_ascii CRASH REPORT Process <0.563.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: call to undefined function xmpp_idna:domain_utf8_to_ascii(<<"XXXXXXXX">>) in p1_server:terminate/7 line 878
```

I suspect I have to install a dependency or something, or maybe the Gentoo ebuild is broken.

I recently updated ejabberd from 18.03 to 18.09 and this is when it started.

I am using dev-erlang/xmpp 1.4.2 on this system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at https://github.com/processone/xmpp/issues/42

xmpp_idna was removed from xmpp library in a commit from 22 September 2019, as released in version 1.4.2:
https://github.com/processone/xmpp/commit/f3517a9adaa4406c614e2234d3af10f1411196b9

So, when ejabberd 19.09 was released, the call to that function in ejabberd_pkix was rewritten, and the requirements were updated accordingly to 1.4.2 library

Now, you are mixing a very recent library, xmpp 1.4.2, with a very old ejabberd, 18.09